# jQuery: fadeIn() isn't working for me, syntax error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fadeout

I'm using mouseover & mouseleave to fade in/out my login/signup buttons. But I can't get them to fade in again? I've tried a few things and everything I find on google confirms that my syntax is fine? I'm not sure.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $('.sign-up').on('mouseover', function(){
    $(this).fadeTo(200, .2)
  })


  $('.sign-up').on('mouseleave', function(){
      $(this).fadeIn(200)
  })

  $('.log-in').on('mouseover', function(){
    $(this).fadeTo(200, .2)
  })


  $('.log-in').on('mouseleave', function(){
      $(this).fadeIn(200)
  })

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fadeTo` method manipulates `opacity` property of the element. You should use `fadeOut` instead or use `fadeTo` again instead of the `fadeIn`. `fadeIn`
and `fadeOut` manipulate the `display` property.

```
$(this).fadeTo(200, 1);
```

You could also minify your code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('.sign-up, .log-in').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
      $(this).fadeTo(200, e.type === "mouseenter" ? .2 : 1);
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. For some reason the fadeOut didn't work for me either, but changing the fadeIn to fadeTo worked.